# On equipartitions of surfaces of 3D convex regions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry

Let S be the surface of a 3D convex region (a 'convex surface'). Let S' be a subset of S. We shall refer to S' as *geodetically convex in S* if the following condition holds: If A and B are two points in S', (at least one of ) the shortest path(s) on S between A and B contains no point that is not in S'.

**Question:** It is easy to see that if S is the surface of a sphere and n is any integer, S can be partitioned into n equal area pieces that are also geodetically convex in S - these pieces are separated by great circle arcs between any 2 antipodal points on S. Prolate and oblate spheroids (and perhaps all surfaces got by rotating a curve about an axis) too *seem* to allow such equipartitions. Are there any other convex surfaces for which such an equipartition exists for *any* n? If so, how does one characterize such surfaces?

**Note 1:** If S is the surface of a cube, I suspect it cannot be cut into n geodetically convex equal area pieces for *all* n. One could also ask which convex surfaces are worst for such equipartitions - ie if there are convex surfaces which do not allow such an equipartition for *any* n.

**Note 2:** Even if we drop the equal area requirement and need the n pieces only to be geodetically convex in S, the question appears tricky for general n. For n=2, since a closed convex surface always has a closed geodesic (as per a theorem of Poincare), such a geodesic cuts a convex surface S into 2 pieces that are geodetically convex in S.

Comment: Concerning the cube, which $n$ do you know about? 2 and 6 are easily "yes", and 4 can be done with each piece consisting of three isosceles right triangles. What about 3 and 5?

Comment: @JukkaKohonen: For $n=3$ on cube, this is natural but fails: Slice with planes parallel to the base at heights $\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$. The middle band fails to be geodetically convex. Another reason that an alternative definition might be preferred.

Comment: @Joseph, that was my first attempt as well. IMHO it just shows that the problem has two possible formulations, a "local" and a "global" one. Both might be interesting in their own right. Perhaps the "local" one that you are proposing would have better title to the name "geodesic" since usually being a geodesic is understood as a local condition (not "globally shortest path").

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find an answer for n=3 or 5 for the cube. Maybe there aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be a cone with lateral side $A$ and base $B$.
So $C = A \cup B$.
The base is geodetically convex.
But if I'm interpreting the definition correctly, $A$ is not
geodetically convex: For any two points $a$ and $b$ on the rim,
the unique shortest path from $a$ to $b$ lies in $B$ (blue in the
figure). The geodesic segment on $A$ (red) is always longer.

[image: Cone]

Perhaps this is the behavior you want. But if not,
you might change the definition to:

> A set $S$ is convex
> if, for every pair of points in $S$, there exists a geodesic segment $\gamma$ connecting them which remains entirely within $S$.

I.e., drop the "shortest path(s)" condition.

Even with this definition, there are what might be considered
anomalies. Consider the cone $C$ minus the apex $x$: $C \setminus \{x\}$.
Then I believe this surface with a point-hole
is convex, because no geodesic passes through $x$.
Again, maybe this is fine, e.g., for smooth surfaces.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, as per our definition, the curved surface of the cone 'A' that you showed cannot be called a geodetically convex subset of the full cone C ('full cone' means the closed surface formed by this curved part and base). And as far as I can make out, C minus the apex is indeed a geodetically convex subset of C.

Comment: And if the full cone surfaced C is cut into 2 finite pieces by a plane parallel to its base, it appears the lower portion (containing the base) will not be geodetically convex in C.